# I am using collection view, I want to make last cell as selected when initially view is loaded and later on user can un select it

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3, uicollectionview

I am using collection view, I want to make last cell as selected when initially view is loaded and later on user can un select it
my codes selects the last cell item but later I am not able to unselect it

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: NibConstants.sizeCollectionViewCellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! SizesFilterationCollectionViewCell
        if(indexPath.row == self.mViewModel.collectionViewDumyArray.count - 1){

            cell.isSelected = true
            cell.sizeLabel.text = self.mViewModel.collectionViewDumyArray[indexPath.row]
        }else{cell.sizeLabel.text = self.mViewModel.collectionViewDumyArray[indexPath.row]}
        
        
       
        return cell
    }
```

[that's the view in which I have selected cell item with text "All" but I want that later it can unselected too](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3MUen.png)

Comment: It is bcz you code is statically cell.isSelected = true . Here you should handle code for making it false when user unselect.

Comment: Use collectionView's `selectCell`.

Comment: how to use select delegate method if you can code hint please

Comment: when I click all cell the deselect delegate method doesn't work